# How do I reduce the size of my symbols.zip?

Tags: unity, android

I am making an Android app in Unity.  Google recommends using a symbols.zip, which Unity auto-generates.  However, the symbols.zip that Unity is generating for my app is over 1 GB, and the max size that Google will accept is 300 MB.

How can I reduce the size of my symbols.zip?

[image]

Comment: Related thread from Unity Forums:  https://forum.unity.com/threads/need-help-with-2-warnings-on-the-google-play-console.923267/

Comment: Here is the right answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69228655/2534246
just delete dbg.so files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows to zip, do not zip the originally extracted folder. Zip the contents of it, then rename.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63544670/unity-android-build-symbols-zip-file-too-big/64267680#64267680

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't solved this yet I ran into the same problem and the solution is stupidly simple:
Unpack the symbols.zip file and repack it.

You'll hopefully get an ok sized symbols file. It seems that Unity is simply very bad at compressing.

*edit*
Rename the compressed file to the same name as the original file

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63544670/unity-android-build-symbols-zip-file-too-big?noredirect=1#comment112890978_63544670)

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. In my case size got reduced from 545 Mb to 140 Mb !

Comment: Reduces the file size, but then when I try to upload:  "The native debug symbols contain an invalid directory my_app.symbols. Only Android ABIs are supported."

Comment: I haven’t tested if it makes a difference, but renaming your zip to the original zip file’s name might be required

Comment: Could it be that the zip contains some hidden/special files, that were accidentally skipped when your re-zipped the unpacked contents you could see? It would be very surprising if Unity left an almost 75% file size reduction on the table unnecessarily, especially with a battle-tested format like .zip.

Comment: @DMGregory Nope, nothing hidden in there, I agree it is surprising, but it it seems so, at least for some of us.
`➜  1.4.5(77)-1.4.5-v77.symbols git:(iOS) ✗ ll -a
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   4 erik  staff   128B Oct  6 20:18 .
drwxr-xr-x  10 erik  staff   320B Oct  6 20:18 ..
drwxr-xr-x   5 erik  staff   160B Oct  6 20:17 arm64-v8a
drwxr-xr-x   5 erik  staff   160B Oct  6 20:16 armeabi-v7a`

Answer (score 0):

I believe Symbols.zip contains debugging symbols used for generating stack traces when an error occurs. It should be safe to remove this, though you might have difficulty diagnosing crash reports.

As an aside, if you're getting 1GB of symbols in a non-debug build, it sounds like something is going wrong with the build system, so this might be something worth reporting to Unity using the bug reporter.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I am already doing ScriptOnly.  It is already removed - I am trying to make it small enough that I can use it.

Comment: @Evorlor If you have any plugins, you might try compiling without the plugins to see if that drastically affects the Symbols size. If it does, there might be a problem with the plugin. Otherwise, if the symbols are 1GB and you're not using "full" stack traces, it sounds like an engine bug you should report using "Help > Report a bug"

Comment: ABSOLUTELY NOT. Stack trace is what you get in the Unity log. Nothing related to Builds.

Comment: @AlexisPautrot You're right, I was thinking of the WebGL "Enable Exceptions" setting "Full with stack trace", which greatly increases the build size on WebGL. However, enabling full stack trace in the regular logging settings will hurt _performance_ on any platform since Unity is logging significantly more information.

Comment: It will hurt performance if something is logged. Which is almost never, unless an exception is throw, or something is logged by your code, or by a 3rd party code you use. I do agree that logging with full stack is not recommended in a release build, unless its an error.